# Akka: Subscriber handling multiple topics

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

public class Subscriber extends UntypedActor
{

```
public Subscriber() {
    ActorRef mediator =
            DistributedPubSub.get(getContext().system()).mediator();
    // subscribe to the topic named "content"
    mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Subscribe("content", getSelf()),
            getSelf());
    mediator.tell(new DistributedPubSubMediator.Subscribe("content_2", getSelf()),
            getSelf());
}

public void onReceive(Object msg) {
    if (msg instanceof String)
        System.out.println("Message received: " + msg );
    else if (msg instanceof DistributedPubSubMediator.SubscribeAck)
        System.out.println("subscribing");
    else
        unhandled(msg);
}
```

}

Now suppose both the topics have the same structure name(e.g. foo) but with different types. In this case how the subscriber will get to know "foo" message has been received from which topic ?

Answer (score 0):

So the DistributedPubSub (DPS) is just a means to get messages to the actor. The receive loop doesn't care if the message is sent via the tell, ask, or via a DPS, it just knows that a message is in its inbox. What is more the DPS is just a router in that it calls forward() on the messages it receives so it doesn't rewrite the sender information of whomever published the message to the DPS. So the answer to your question is that you wont know what DPS it came in on and I think if that matters there is probably something wrong with the design. I cant think of a valid reason why that would be significant rather than the sender of the original message or the actual type of the message itself. So I would do my switching and checking on the types and if I needed to know where it came from, from the path of the ActorRef.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't get your answer completely. Is it possible for a Subscriber to subscribe to more than 1 topic ?

Comment: Oh definitely. Quite common in fact. Just creates additional means to get messages into the actor. I have a very large actor based system and some of the actors have several subscriptions which subscribe to messages produced by several sources. I would, in fact, suggest a topic per producing actor and let consumers decide what they want to listen to. Just make sure that if you dont want to handle messages you consume them rather than sending them to undandled (thus dead letters).

Comment: Thanks. I am new to this topic stuff. 1)Can I use the ActorRef as the topic name or its a bad design? 2)Is there a way to know whether a particular Topic name is already being used in the entire cluster 3)Suppose(the original question that I had asked) the Subscriber subscribes to 2 Topics & lets assume that both the Topics are publishing same type of information/message/object, now how will the Subscriber know the message has come from which Topic.

Comment: 1. I wouldn't do that. Actor path perhaps but not actor ref.
2. Not that I know of. I unusually use the fully qualified class name of the producing actor as the topic.
3. As I said in my answer, it wont. You would have to tag the message somehow, adding data necessary. The question I would pose is why you need to know.